# How to pass a value to anotherviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Hello everybody, I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`.  When a row in the table is tapped I am collecting the cell's text value and putting it in a string called `localstringGValue`.

I want to pass this string and display it in another, `viewController`, but without using `-pushViewController`: I want this value to be stored somewhere like `NSUserDefaults` or `NSDictonary` and then, on `viewWillapper` of the other view controller I want this stored value to be displayed in a label.

in my `.h`:

```
 NSString *localStringGValue;
```

in my `.m`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    localStringGValue = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text; 
}
```

in my other view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
    label.text=localStringGValue;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simple case of delegate and protocols... http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: search about Delegate variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save to nsuserdefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:localstringGValue forKey:@"localstringGValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

retrieve from nsuserdefaults:

```
NString *localstringGValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"localstringGValue"];
```

Comment: Is that a good way to use `NSUserDefaults` for storing dynamic value?

Comment: How would you define "good" in this context? It's just one way to use as and when you feel it's sensible. Sometimes I use a mix of notifications and delegates instead. However, mostly I use a distinct model class. For a small infrequent amount of data and a simple option nsuserdefaults can sometimes suffice. We all have to walk before we can run.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `delegate`. Before you push the 'UploadViewController' instance, you need set it's `delegate` as `self`(in GoogleDocMainPageController.m). Everytime, the tabel cell is selected, it'll set value for `self.delegate`(Here is GoogleDocMainPageController instance) by dispatching `self.delegate`'s method, which is implemented by GoogleDocMainPageController:

```
[self.delegate setDataAfterSelectedTabelCell:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TalbeCell %d selected", [indexPath row]]];
```

The main code is shown below:
UploadViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class UploadViewController;

@protocol UploadViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)setDataAfterSelectedTabelCell:(NSString *)stringValueInCell;

@end

@interface UploadViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <UploadViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

UploadViewController.m:

```
//...
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

//...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.delegate setDataAfterSelectedTabelCell:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TalbeCell %d selected", [indexPath row]]];
}
```

GoogleDocMainPageController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "UploadViewController.h"

@class UploadViewController;

@interface GoogleDocMainPageController : UIViewController <UploadViewControllerDelegate>

- (void)loadUploadViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel * glLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UploadViewController * uploadViewController;

@end
```

GoogleDocMainPageController.m:

```
//...
@synthesize glLabel = _glLabel;
@synthesize uploadViewController = _uploadViewController;

//...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton * uploadButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 160.0f, 300.0f, 35.0f)];
    [uploadButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [uploadButton setTitle:@"Upload Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [uploadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadUploadViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:uploadButton];
    [uploadButton release];

    self.glLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 200.0f, 300.0f, 35.0f)];
    [self.glLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.glLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.glLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [self.glLabel setText:@"Default"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.glLabel];

    self.uploadViewController = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
}

//...
#pragma mark -

- (void)loadUploadViewController
{
    [self.uploadViewController setDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.uploadViewController animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - UploadViewControllerDelegate

- (void)setDataAfterSelectedTabelCell:(NSString *)stringValueInCell
{
    [self.glLabel setText:stringValueInCell];
}
```

Comment: sir i didn't understand this code:// Then just show your another view controller
- (void)theMethodDispatchAnotherViewController
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.yourAnotherViewController animated:YES];
} where did i put this code?

Comment: so in viewwillappear of another view controller i want to put lbel.text = self.yourAnotherviewcontroller right?

Comment: @ICoder it just a sample method, you can put it in your `.m` file. Well, forget it, just use your `self.yourAnotherViewController` when you need to display your `another view`.

Comment: so label.text =self.yourAnotherViewController; in the viewwillapper of the anotherviewcontroller

Comment: @ICoder, nope, it's `label.text = self.localStringGValue;`, localStringGValue is declared in `YourAnotherViewController.h`.

Comment: sir we want to set property of localStringGValue in another view controller?i get an error that property not font in viewcontroller

Comment: @ICoder of course, you need declare property for `localStringGValue` in your another view controller. Just take a minute to see the new version. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5775/discussion-between-icoder-and-kjuly)

Comment: @ICoder maybe you'll like this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare some `@property(nonatomic,retain)` and `@synthesize` it ? Then the getters/setters will be automatically created. Otherwise, define some getter/setters yourself.

Comment: i alerdy diclared it,but s i said earlier i didn't ant that value to pas in page redirection code ,i just want that value to displayed in label when i tap the tableview cell

Answer (score 0):

Go through Following Steps-

In First ViewController -

1. Create Object of second ViewController
   like  SecondViewController *sec= [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    sec.myLable=@"My Lable String";

   In Second ViewController -
2. In .h file
   UILable *myLable;

   @property(nonautomic,retain)IBOutlet UILable *myLable;

   2.In .m file
   @synthesize myLable;